# What is the most efficient method for adding/removing classes from DOM elements using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, css

I'm iterating over a large number of dom elements in Javascript, and I'd like to add/remove classes as appropriate.

What's the most efficient add/remove class operation I can use?

Comment: What've you tried? Have you tried to bench-mark your approaches? What sort of mark-up are you working with?

Comment: If the browser supports it: [`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList). Or just have a look at the jQuery implementation of `addClass` and `removeClass`. Should be fairly efficient.

Comment: I can't think of anything simpler than setting `className` in javascript, but the quickest way to style many elements at once could be CSS selectors. Depending on what you want to achieve, you may not need to touch classes at all.

Comment: I would use jQuery if possible since it hides the different browser implementations. Not all use className as the attribute afaik.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Small class strings: [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/best-way-to-remove-class).
- Bigger class strings: [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/best-way-to-remove-class/2).
- Bigger class strings, repeated class names: [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/best-way-to-remove-class/3).

### Remove

The fastest reliable way (small/medium size):

```
var clss = 'classToRemove';
elem.className = (' '+elem.className+' ').split(' ' + clss + ' ').join(' ');
```

If you know for sure that the string does not contain multiple occurrences of the same class name, you can better use the `string.replace` method (any size):

```
var clss = 'classToRemove';
elem.className = (' '+elem.className+' ').replace(' ' + clss + ' ', ' ');
```

The other alternatives:

- Using a RegExp in combination with replace - Slow in all cases
- Using `indexOf` to find the position, and use string concatenation (substring) to remove the class (repeat this in a loop to remove all possible duplicates).
  **Slowest** for large strings **with repetition**, not slow neither fast in other cases.

### Add (without doubt):

```
var clss = 'classToAdd';
element.className += ' ' + clss;
```

Comment: This doesn't check if the class already exists before adding it =]

The remove also fails if the class is the first or last in the list (as it wouldn't have a leading or trailing space).

Comment: Here is another [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/adding-removing-classes), using a stripped down version of jQuery's implementation. [Here is yours including `classList`](http://jsperf.com/best-way-to-remove-class/4).

Comment: `indexOf` + `substring` is surprisingly fast in Chrome.

Comment: @FelixKling I have added 2 additional (total 3) JSPerfs. indexOf + substring is slow for large class names with repeated classes, and fast nor slow for other strings.As for your stripped benchmark, that's not a fair benchmark. One of your test cases have the overhead of a function call.

Comment: So useful on IE 8! Thanks! I just modified a bit the "ADD" part in order to remove the class when it exists.

Answer (score 1):

The bottleneck is in retrieving the elements, not adding/removing class names.

`el.className = "another_class"; //Simple`

Depending on the structure of your DOM, you can optimize element retrieval by practicing the following:

- Getting a particular wrapper element via `getElementById`
- Getting related sub-elements with `getElementsByTagName` or `childNodes` (depending which is more appropriate for the situation)
- If referenced recursively, saving references to the accessed elements

Typically, a framework will retrieve elements much more slowly than a vanilla Javacript method, but if you save references by dumping accessed elements in a local array, the difference is near negligible.

---

**Edit:** `getElementsByClassName` is another way to retrieve elements, but it isn't as well supported as the above methods yet.

Again, if we could see your code, we could give a more direct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Where supported, element.classList is around **1000 times faster** than Rob_W's best suggestions (no ie8/9 support, although a fallback from Mozilla exists).

http://jsperf.com/best-way-to-remove-class/6

Rob_W's tests were flawed because they were not using the DOM-- just really testing the performance of various string replacements (see tests).

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery:

```
function addClass(domElement, class) {
    var classes = domElement.getAttribute("className");

    if (!classes.indexOf(class))
        classes += " " + class;

    domElement.setAttribute("className", classes);
}

function removeClass(domElement, class) {
    domElement.setAttribute("className", domElement.getAttribute("className").replace(class, ""));
}
```

Comment: `removeClass` would modify classes that only have a substring of the class to be removed. Same problem with `addClass`, it will give false positives not to mention `indexOf` returns -1 when the substring isn't found